# How to consume streaming JSON data from an HTTP call in Java

Tags: java, json, http

I am trying to switch to a new data feed provider API that works fine in CURL with this command

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.activetick.com/stream.json?sessionid=12225759b81b421a9ce69db19c9222d8&symbols=AAPL_S-U,IBM_S-U' -H "Connection: Keep-Alive" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

Our system is running in Java and I am unsure how to build code that can consume the JSON formatted messages the stream provides, below is how I am trying to do it now and when reading from in the input stream returned it throws unexpected end of line exception.

```
static  void test() throws IOException {
        try {
            HttpsURLConnection c = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://api.activetick.com/stream.json?sessionid=12225759b81b421a9ce69db19c9222d8&symbols=AAPL_S-U,IBM_S-U")
                    .openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("POST");
            c.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "json");
            c.connect();
            InputStream io = c.getInputStream();
            
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(io);
            ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            for (int result = bis.read(); result != -1; result = bis.read()) {
                buf.write((byte) result);
            }       
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("here");
        }
    
        
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out DataFetcher (https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java) this is the answer to your question

Comment: Fix Accept-Encoding to match your CURL use, eg. not 'json' but 'application/json'

Comment: Thanks for the catch on application/json updated it but still having issues.

Comment: I would expect the [`Accept-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) header to be used to specify a compression format (`gzip`, `deflate` and so on). I think you need [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) instead: `"Accept: application/json"`. Or, for your Java code, `c.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");`. This may not be sufficient to solve your problem - but I think it will be necessary.

Comment: 2 changes in the code and you should be good to go..  c.setRequestMethod("GET"); c.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

Comment: @active_coder thanks you are right, its a GET not a post!